# Inner join 3 different tables codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, inner-join

I need to join three tables that acquires each other (not centralized to just a table)

1st table: **attendance**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|   id    |   emp_code   |   emp_name   |  date    |   time   |
|   001   |   TNY        |   Tony       |01.01.2001|   07.00  |
|   002   |   PPR        |   Pepper     |01.01.2001|   07.50  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

2nd table: **employee**

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|   emp_code   |   emp_name   |division_code|  address  |
|   TNY        |   Tony       |    D001     |  New york |
|   PPR        |   Pepper     |    D002     | California|
---------------------------------------------------------
```

3rd table: **division**

```
-----------------------------
|division_code|division_name|
|   D001      |   Finance   |
|   D002      |  Marketing  |
-----------------------------
```

The result i want to get would be:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   id    |   emp_code   |   emp_name   |division_name|  date    |   time   |
|   001   |   TNY        |   Tony       |  Finance    |01.01.2001|   07.00  |
|   002   |   PPR        |   Pepper     |  Marketing  |01.01.2001|   07.50  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My code from my model:

```
    function ShowData()
{
    $this->db->select('attendance.emp_code, attendance.emp_name,division.division_name,attendance.date,attendance.time');    
    $this->db->from('attendance');
    $this->db->join('employee', 'employee.emp_code = attendance.emp_code');
    $this->db->join('division', 'employee.division_code = division.division_code');
    $query = $this->db->get();
}
```

The result of my code is nothing, no data is shown, and i think it is because of my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method isn't `returning` anything:

```
$this->db->selct('a.id, a.emp_code, a.emp_name, d.divison_node, a.date, a.time');
$this->db->join('employee AS e', 'e.emp_code = a.emp_code');
$this->db->join('division AS d', 'd.division_code = e.division_code');
return $this->db->get('attendance AS a')->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the final data getter:

```
function ShowData()
{
    $this->db->select('attendance.emp_code, attendance.emp_name,division.division_name,attendance.date,attendance.time');    
    $this->db->from('attendance');
    $this->db->join('employee', 'employee.emp_code = attendance.emp_code');
    $this->db->join('division', 'employee.division_code = division.division_code');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $data = $query->result_array(); // here will be stored the selected data as an array

}
```

The `$this->db->get();` just creates an SQL statement using the CI query builder and executes it, **it does not** return the SQL output data, you just receive an object of the query itself.

But `$query->result_array();` gets the SQL output data and formates the data for you - to an array in this case.

If you want to return the data, just add this line to your function body:

```
return $data;
```